# Are drivers needed before installing new motherboard on linux?

Tags: linux, drivers

I have Ubuntu 14.04, 32 bit and I want to install new Celeron G18xx on [Intel H81 chipset](http://ark.intel.com/products/75016/Intel-DH82H81-PCH). Do I need to check my kernel before replacing hardware? Will I be able to:

- boot
- auto mount partitions (UUID entries in /etc/fstab)
- see desktop (or tty) on chipset VGA output

Or should I take some precautions? In particular, installing drivers for new chipset and built-in gpu?

Comment: We need more information about your system.

Comment: Yes, more information.  The answer lies in the old and new hardware, most importantly the network and disk subsystem, although you can fix the network later if you are at the console.  98% of systems now use the standard SATA drivers, even hardware raid is usually compatible.  You need to describe your hardware (to and from) in detail, especially the disk subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Grub uses the system bios to load the kernel and initrd. Then the kernel takes over and has to either have the needed drivers compiled in or available as modules in the initrd to be able continue and mount the drives.

**The drivers for the onboard disk controllers on the new mother board has to be included in the initrd.**